# PDO Compression not supported

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I'm trying to use compression on my PDO connection, connecting to MariaDb. However, when I try to get the attribute I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute
```

I am using PHP `7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4`, with MariaDb `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB`

My code to create the connection is as follows:

```
protected function connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbName, $port = null, $useCompression = false)
{
    //Already connected? Just return true.
    if ($this->connected) return true;

    $dsn = "mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$host;dbname=$dbName";
    if ($port) $dsn .= ";port=$port";

    $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS => $useCompression
    ];

    // Setup DB connection
    $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);

    $this->connected = true;
}
```

I get a reference to the PDO object (`$pdo`) in a PHPUnit test and then try this:

```
$this->assertTrue($pdo->getAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS));
```

This results in the error at the beginning of this post.

Why do I get this error? According to the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) this should work since PHP 5.3.11.

Answer (score 0):

`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS` is only constraint.

To use compression server and client must allow for it.